# Mixing exceptions management and thread-safe calls in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

As every good developer well-knowns, mixing exceptions management and thread-safe calls is always something *delicate*.

For the first time, I am dealing with this kind of scenario in **Python**. 
I known that in Python 2.5 and later, it is possible to use the `with` statement as follows:

> When used with a lock, this statement automatically acquires the lock
>   before entering the block, and releases it when leaving the block:
>
> ```
> from __future__ import with_statement # 2.5 only
>
> with lock:
>     ... access shared resource
> ```

Considering this sample code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import threading

def static_vars(**kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        for k in kwargs:
            setattr(func, k, kwargs[k])
        return func
    return decorate

lock = threading.Lock();

@static_vars(counter = 0)
def ts_increment():
    with lock:
        try:
            // something else, also thread-safe
            ts_increment.counter += 1
        except:
            raise
```

Would the *lock* be released if an exception will be caught and re-thrown by the `raise` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if an exception is raised within a with statement, the lock will be released.

```
>>> import threading
>>> l = threading.Lock()
>>> with l:
    raise

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in <module>
    raise
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
>>> l.acquire() # see if we can lock the lock.
True
```

Sidenote: If you look in to the working of the with statement, `l.__enter__` is called when entering the statement and `l.__exit__` is always called on exit with error information or `None`. See [pep 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) section "Specification: The 'with' Statement".